# Change mouse cursor to pointer in charts js

Tags: chart.js

I'm using ChartJs and datalabels plugin and i would like to add the mouse cursor to pointer in chart it is possible ?

I was following the example of the [official](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com) website, Can someone help me?

```
data: {
  datasets: [{
    datalabels: {
      listeners: {
        click: function(context) {
          console.log('label ' + context.dataIndex + ' has been clicked!');
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
      //...
  }]
},
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      listeners: {
        enter: function(context) {
          context.hovered = true;
          return true;
        },
        leave: function(context) {
          // Receives `leave` events for any labels of any dataset.
          context.hovered = false;
          return true;
        }
      },
      color: function(context) {
        // Change the label text color based on our new `hovered` context value.
        return context.hovered ? "blue" : "gray";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. When hovering on a specific label and changes the cursor to pointer.

```
 listeners: {
                enter: function(context) {

                  context.hovered = true;
                  var el = document.getElementById("myLineChart");
                  el.style.cursor = "pointer";
                  return true;
                },
                leave: function(context) {
                  context.hovered = false;
                  var el = document.getElementById("myLineChart");
                  el.style.cursor = "default";
                  return true;
                },
              },
```

It resets when stopping from hovering the label. I hope helps.

Comment: That's what I needed, works fine. Thank you very much!